# Ocaml first-class module and extended variant

Tags: types, module, ocaml, first-class

I tried to use first-class module by implementing this piece of code :

```
module Component =
  struct

    type t_data = ..

    module type S =
      sig
        type t
        val create : t -> t_data
      end

    module Make (C: sig type t end) =
      struct
        type t = C.t
        type t_data += T of C.t
        let create data = T data
      end

  end

let create m data =
  let module M = (val m : Component.S) in M.create data

(*  The type constructor M.t would escape its scope *)
```

I would also try this alternative but I don't know how to add the extended type t_data in the module S :

```
let create' m data =
  let module M = (val m : Component.S) in M.T data
(* Unbound constructor M.T *)
```

I'm using bucklescript, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need some extra annotations to convince the typechecker:

```
let create (type t0) (m : (module Component.S with type t = t0)) data =
  let module M = (val m) in M.create data
```

Which can be shorten into:

```
let create (type t0) (module M : Component.S with type t = t0) data =
  M.create data
```

The `(type t)` annotation introduces a *local* abstract datatype. Outside the function, this type is turned into a universal type variable, thus given the type:

```
val create : (module Component.S with type t = 'a) -> 'a -> Component.t_data
```

You can use the locally abstract type like any other type, notably you can put it in locally defined modules as well:

```
let inject (type t0) data =
  let module M0 = struct type t = t0 end in
  let module M = Component.Make(M0) in
  M.create data
val make : 'a -> Component.t_data
```

Comment: Also, do you know what it means that M.t would escape its scope ? What I understand is the typechecker checks only the Component.S (and argument m is not a part of the process) who contains an abstract type waiting to be defined by the caller ?

Comment: It more or less means that your function would return a type for which the outside environment has no name. Here, `M.t` has no name outside because it's hidden inside the value `m`. In this case, it's more or less an artifact of the incomplete type inference: the final type go through a type variable instead.

Comment: Understood for the most part, quite a big beast to tame ! Thank you sensei